# ckeditor - Pure HTML source mode without ANY alterations of the code

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I know this question has been asked 1000 times, but after 6 hours of research I still couldn't find any solution.

Unfortunately, I am bound to a CMS that's using ckeditor. I don't like WYSIWYG editors at all, but I have to deal with it. I want the editor to not touch ANY of my code, doesn't matter if it's wrong or not, if I place block elements into inline elements, etc.

This is the config I am using atm:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.language = 'en';
config.allowedContent = true;
config.height = 600;
config.startupMode = 'source';

// Prevent CK from removing empty HTML-tags
$.each(CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty, function (i, value) {
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty[i] = false;
});};
```

Well, with these settings the editor still seems to alter the code. For instance, it realigns `<a>` or `<span>` tags and just adds new code. This is so incredible annoying. I know it's not the purpose of the editor to behave like a pure webdev editor, but there must be a way to configure it somehow to just leave the code completely alone, right? Can anyone tell me what settings I need to add in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> there must be a way to configure it somehow to just leave the code completely alone, right?

Wrong.

Libraries like this make use of the `contentEditable` feature provided by browsers.

The browser will take the HTML, parse it into a DOM, and then provide an API to manipulate it. Later, that DOM can be serialised back to HTML, but this is entirely disconnected from the original HTML. Everything will have been normalised.

Comment: What's really weird is, if I am pasting HTML with CSS into the source window and directly save it, the code is not altered at all. Everything is shown correctly on the website and the source code is not altered. But once I go back into the CK, it starts to alter the code. This led me to the conclusion that there must be a way. I mean it works, but only to the point until I edit the content again.

Comment: I just described how the content editing mechanism works. It doesn't work in a way that lets you do what you want.

Comment: Well thanks. Do you know any open source editor that would let me do what I want to do and which I can implement into a CMS? Don't need WYSIWYG at all.

Comment: If you don't need wysiwyg then use the textarea and your code will never be changed. All the editors in wysiwyg/design mode deal with "live" HTML and have operated according to the specification. The reason why it has worked for you in source mode is because there is textarea used and this HTML is treated as plain text. Validation is applied in wysiwyg/design mode. So once again either you start using valid HTML or the only option is switching to plain textarea.